# Custom cell clear background?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview in a view controller that is dynamically populated with data from a database. Now I have set the tableview to be clear and it working correctly, but I have tried to set the cells to be clear to no avail ?

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

That line has been placed in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little extension should help you.

The idea is to set the `backgorundView` to clear too and not just the `backgroundColor`:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func setTransparent() {
        let bgView: UIView = UIView()
        bgView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()

        self.backgroundView = bgView
        self.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add the following line:

```
cell.setTransparent()
```

Comment: I have tried this just now, but it it showing the white background still, I have an image as the view controllers background which should be seen instead.

Comment: Did you set the background for the tableView too? `tableView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()`

Comment: I believe I have: via the interface builder iv'e set the tableviews bakground colour to clear. Could it be that the background of the viewcontroller is set via imageview ?

Comment: I have tried your way to set the tableviews background to clear rather than the interface builder, and it is working. thanks :)